Why is A = LU form preferred over EA = U?
I am studying MIT's linear algebra course (18.06) from open course ware.
In the lecture regarding $A=LU$ factorization, professor Strang said he prefers $EA = U$ form of expression than that of $A=LU$. Since I did not get it right a way, I looked at its textbook and lecture summary. It gives an example below:

In case of $EA=U$, $E_{32}E_{21}=E$ is below:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
10 & -5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In case of $A=LU$, $L=E_{21}^{-1}E_{32}^{-1}$ is below:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$


So it explains that there is no left-bottom corner $10$ in the latter case, and thus it is preferred over than the former.
However, I still do not fully understand why due to one reasons:
Why is that left-bottom so annoying? We can get that number just by multiplying the multipliers we used during the elimination step (i.e., $-2$ and $-5$). The lecture note says:
"The 10 in the lower left corner arises because we subtracted twice the first row from the second row, then subtracted five times the new second row from the third. The factorization A = LU is preferable to the statement EA = U because the combination of row subtractions does not have the effect on L that it did on E."
If there is anything incorrect, please let me know.
Thank you for taking your time.

@Moo A is (1, 2, 1 \ 3, 8, 1 \ 0, 4, 1), three by three matrix.

@Moo Thank you for the comment. I understand the steps how to get $E$ matrix and $L$ from that (i.e., steps of reversing the elimination). The main point of my question was  then why the professor said he prefers the $A=LU$ form over $EA=U$. The reason he provided during the lecture is because $E$ has annoying number 10 on its bottom-left corner, whereas $L$ does not (it only has multiplies along its main diagonal. However, I do not understand why that 10 is so problem that we have to do additional calculations to get $L$, even though we already can solve the system with $E$.

If there is any unclear expression, please let me know. Sorry for my bad English.
